# Detect text in textbox even when pagesource shows textbox previous value

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

My question is very simple if the DOM does not have a textbox value which user types how does javascript  detect the latest text typed by the user in the browser

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showalert() {
            var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtbx.ClientID %>').value;
            alert(x);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox>
            <input type="submit" onclick="return showalert();" value="OK" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

above is my code.
The page source does not show the latest text typed by user in textbox.
The code works similarly across all browsers and all VS editions.
I even run the code on a plain HTML page without a Visual Studio

Comment: i posted answer try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page pretty much answers everything.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1069194.aspx?Client+side+changes+not+reflected+in+page

Re: Client side changes not reflected in page
Oct 22, 2007 04:14 PM|LINK

Changes made by  javascript are held in the memory, they are not reflected on the page. When the form is submitted, browser submits the changed value. Change your hidden field to a text box or something, you can see the value being updated on the page. But when you view the source, you will find the old value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

due to  `return false;` click event will not fire or use  `return true;`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showalert() 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById('<%=txtbx.ClientID %>').value;
            alert(x);

        }
    </script>
```

and always define ID and Name for HTML elements

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" onclick="return showalert();" value="OK" />
```

Comment: That is exactly my point with return false the page is not posted back to the server but still the javascript detects latest value in textbox how come?

Comment: it will always return latest value in textbox